# Why does RatNum not have a ToDecimal() method?

Tags: .net, z3

I'd like to convert a RatNum expression to a Dot Net decimal. RatNum has a ToDecimalString method but not a ToDecimal method. Is there any reason for this? Is there any other way to convert a RatNum to a decimal other than Decimal.Parse(ratnum.ToDecimalString(2))? Thanks.

Comment: Who are you asking, and what answer are you expecting? It's like asking why string doesn't have a `ToWhatShouldICallIt()` method, you'd have to ask the programmer who made the framework.

Comment: Patrick: This question was about the managed API for Microsoft Research's Z3 theorem prover. The question was correctly tagged and indeed directed to the developer of the framework :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer to this question is that System.Decimal type is a (non-IEEE 754) floating point format, while Z3's RatNum is an infinite-precision format for rationals. This is needed because the decimal expansion of a rational number is not necessarily finite (e.g. for 1/3).

We can use ToStringDecimal which takes a precision p and produces a decimal string representation of the rational which has up to p digits. Note that this can be more digits than fit into an Int64 or a Single/Double/Decimal.

Alternatively, we can use ToString which produces a precise representation, e.g. '1/3'.

There are also functions to obtain the numerator and the denominator of the rational which can then be used to produce a decimal in other formats.

So, the long answer is: Z3 is infinitely precise and if the solution needs to be approximated, this has to be done outside of Z3, either by the suggested method of conversion to/from strings, or via other conversions, for instance

```
x.Numerator.Int / x.Denominator.Int
```

if it is known that those integers will not exceed the maximum values for the int type and if the application does not suffer from the floating point approximation of the result.